# Cannot access private property Symfony\Component\Debug\ErrorHandler::$loggedErrors

Tags: php, symfony, error-handling, php-7.1, symfony-3.4

I have recently upgraded to **PHP 7.1** and **Symfony 3.4**. Since then, I have seen in logs the following error message **"Cannot access private property Symfony\Component\Debug\ErrorHandler::$loggedErrors"**.

Looking for the root cause, I have found that at some point an exception is thrown when trying to serialize an object on which a property was unset. This error will be handled in **"Symfony\Component\Debug\ErrorHandler"** in method **"handleError"**. When arriving at [line 388](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/3.4/src/Symfony/Component/Debug/ErrorHandler.php#L388) from **"handleError"** method (`$log = $this->loggedErrors & $type;`) the exception with cannot access private property $loggedErrors will be generated, even if "$this" is an instance of "Symfony\Component\Debug\ErrorHandler".
Also, I've seen that at the same line, when a deprecation is detected, will not throw the exception with cannot access private property.

Has anyone else seen this behavior? Can someone explain why in one case it can access the private property and in the other one it cannot access it?

Comment: Post a link to your full logs for a request that exhibits it so we can see the trace